# Construct a distribution over these variables such that (X1 not independent of X2) but (X1 is independent of X2 | Y)

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Q) Consider three Boolean valued random variables X1, X2 and Y. Construct a distribution over these variables such that (X1 not independent of X2) but (X1 is independent of X2 | Y). Carefully justify why your construction satisfies the desired properties.

I am thinking something along the terms of taking Y to be identically 1.
And $X_1 = X_2 + Y\mod2 $, which can given Y make $X_1$ identically 0 or 1, and make it independent of $X_2$ given Y. But I'm unable to formulate it properly.

Any hints can be a great help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $Y$ is identically $0$ or $1$, I doubt it is possible to change the dependence between $X_1$ and $X_2$ depending on the knowledge of $Y$.

Comment: What else can help in this case?

Comment: Have you considered $X_1=XY$ and $X_2=X'Y$ where $X,X',Y$ are independent Bernoulli$(1/2)$ variables?

Comment: @nejimban thanks!, I had not considered that, but now looking at it, it solves the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in comments.